# Google Sheets Dialog with Dropdown and Insert Row into Named Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

I have a sheet that my company uses to keep track of open shifts within the company. I want the script to add rows into the proper named range on the proper sheet. The user will select an account from the drop down and put in a number of open shifts. The number of open shifts will be added as rows to the account via a Named Range. The code for "This Week" will insert rows into two separate sheets via a Named Range. (This Week, This Week_writeonce)

Here is the code I have so far,

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp
   .getUi()
   .createMenu("Add Holes")
   .addItem("Add Holes for This Week", "showThisWeekSidebar")
   .addItem("Add Holes for Next Week", "showNextWeekSidebar")
   .addToUi();
}

function showThisWeekSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('This Week');

  // Add the dropdown lists to the template
  html.namedRangesDPDWN = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("Named Ranges!NamedRanges").getValues();

  // Keep adding the variables you need based on the ranges containing your dropdown values
  // ...

  // Prepares the template to be shown in the UI
  html = html.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Company Name')
      .setWidth(200);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function showNextWeekSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Next Week');

  // Add the dropdown lists to the template
  html.namedRangesDPDWN = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("Named Ranges!NamedRanges").getValues();

  // Keep adding the variables you need based on the ranges containing your dropdown values
  // ...

  // Prepares the template to be shown in the UI
  html = html.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Company Name')
      .setWidth(200);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Below is the HTML code.

```
<center>
<body bgcolor="#99a3a4">
  <font face="arial" color="black">
    <b>Add Holes for This Week</b><br><br>

    <!-- Create input fields to accept values from the user -->
    Account:<br>
    <select id="Named Ranges">
    <? for (let i in namedRangesDPDWN) { ?>
      <option value="<?=namedRangesDPDWN[i]?>"><?=namedRangesDPDWN[i]?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>
    <br><br>

 <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="numberOfHoles"># of Open Shifts</label><br>
    <input type='text' name='email' id="email" required="required"/>
    </div><br>

  <div>
    <button type="submit"id="submit-form">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Trying to get the code to count the number of rows in named range, if greater than 2, do not account for existing rows.

```
// Take the Account and number of holes from
// the sidebar and insert rows to the proper named range
function insertRowNext(account,n_rows) {  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Next Week');  // Change to your sheet name
    
    //Replace space with underscore
    account=account.replace(/ /g,"_");
    var nameRange = 'Next Week!'+account;
    var range = ss.getRangeByName(nameRange);
    var rangeRows = range.getNumRows();
    n_rows-=1;
    
    if(rangeRows == 2){
      //add row      
      ws.insertRowsBefore(range.getLastRow(),n_rows);
      //Show all rows in the namedRange
      ws.showRows(range.getRow(),range.getNumRows()+n_rows);
      
    }
    else if (rangeRows > 2) {
      //add row      
      ws.insertRowsBefore(range.getLastRow(),n_rows+1);
      //Show all rows in the namedRange
      ws.showRows(range.getRow(),range.getNumRows()+n_rows+1);
    }
 }
```

Here is the sample sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zxdqkksdORfAUlmhnQmefKpxn8n-hB-3YeHdRiNLCLs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet? [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: I was able to add a sample sheet

Comment: Hi sorry I got lost in your namedRanges. Basically, you already have a working sidebar with a dropdown list from `Named Ranges!H1:H40`. Based on my understanding, you will select a name range on the dropdown list and it will add new rows from the name range selected? But when I checked your named ranges, example I selected `Bear Creek` it doesn't exist. While `Bear_Creek` on the other hand has `#REF` value under named range. Where do you expect to add the rows when `Bear Creek` is selected?

Comment: Although I am not able to help you fix the code issue, I would like to suggest you to adjust the colour in your sheet as it is very uncomfortable by looking at the sheet only....

Comment: The named range Bear_Creek will never have rows added,it will always be on either This Week and This Week_writeonce, or Next Week sheets. There is a template sheet that contains all the "bare" named ranges that duplicates to This Week and Next Week.

Comment: Sorry I really did not fully understood your expected output. Can you share a sample scenario starting from the time you select and input data in your sidebar and its result

Comment: To add holes for this week a user would go to the custom menu and select "Add Holes for This Week", the sidebar will open and the user will select the account they want. They will then put in a number (number of rows to add minus 1) and press the submit button. The script will then find the proper named range (all formatted that spaces are _ ) and add the number of rows to the named range and expand the range if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for this sample code! It works almost perfectly. The issue I am facing is that the sheet has each named range grouped and collapsed. When the script adds the rows to the named range, the collapsed row gets hidden and the other rows are added. Can we make it so that the grouped named range will expand if the group is collapsed?

Comment: I updated the answer and include `ws.showRows(range.getRow(),range.getNumRows()+n_rows);`. When you add new rows under a specific namedRange, it will unhide all rows under the namedRange including the newly added rows

Comment: I have run into one small problem. If you have already added rows and need to add more, the amount of rows is one less due to the script taking into account for the already placed row when starting fresh. How would I get the number of rows added for the second or more time reflect accurately?

Comment: It is already shown in the code. when you get your range `var range = ss.getRangeByName(nameRange);` you can get the current number of range row using `range.getNumRows()`. I wasn't able to notice your previous query since you are replying in your post comment rather than the answer posted. It did not gave me notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is a sample code: (For Add Holes This Week menu only)

**This Week.html:**

```
<center>
<body bgcolor="#99a3a4">
  <font face="arial" color="black">
    <b>Add Holes for This Week</b><br><br>

    <!-- Create input fields to accept values from the user -->
    Account:<br>
    <select id="Named Ranges">
    <? for (let i in namedRangesDPDWN) { ?>
      <option value="<?=namedRangesDPDWN[i]?>"><?=namedRangesDPDWN[i]?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>
    <br><br>

 <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="numberOfHoles"># of Open Shifts</label><br>
    <input type='text' name='email' id="email" required="required"/>
    </div><br>

  <div>
    <button type="submit"id="submit-form" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    function processInput(){
      var account = document.getElementById("Named Ranges").value;
      var count = document.getElementById("email").value;

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).insertRowThis(account,count);
    }

    function success(){
      alert("Row added successfully");
    }
  </script>
```

**Modifications:**

- I added a script to call `processInput()` when submit button was clicked.
- In `processInput()`,It will get the account selected and # of open shifts. Then pass them as an argument and call `insertRowThis()` in the server side.

> We used [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) to call server-side Apps Script function which will then call the client-side callback function to run when the server responds. In this example the client-side callback is `success()`

**addHolesMenu.gs**

```
 function insertRowThis(account,n_rows) { 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName('This Week');
    
    //Replace space with underscore
    account=account.replace(/ /g,"_");
    var nameRange = 'This Week!'+account;
    n_rows-=1;
    Logger.log(nameRange);
    Logger.log(n_rows);
    if(n_rows>0){
      //add row
      var range = ss.getRangeByName(nameRange);
      Logger.log(range.getRow());
      Logger.log(range.getLastRow());
      ws.insertRowsBefore(range.getLastRow(),n_rows);
      //Show all rows in the namedRange
      ws.showRows(range.getRow(),range.getNumRows()+n_rows);
    }
 }
```

**Modifications:**

- I added `insertRowThis()` which accepts 2 parameters
- Since this menu is for adding rows in sheet `This Week`. I selected that particular sheet using [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).
- Replace `space` with `underscore` in the account's name
- Subtract 1 from the row input count
- Create a nameRange string to get the specific range in sheet `This Week`. Then use [Spreadsheet.getRangeByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename)
- Insert the desired number of rows before the end of the namedRange. The reason behind this is because, if we insert the row after the last row of the namedRange, it won't be included in the namedRange itself. To automatically adjust the namedRange when adding additional rows, it should be added before the last row of the namedRange.
- Show all the rows under the namedRange including the newly added rows

### Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### (Update)

Add formula in column E:

```
// ==========================================================================================================
// Take the Account and number of holes from
// the sidebar and insert rows to the proper named range
function insertRowThis(account,n_rows) {  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName('This Week');  // Change to your sheet name
    
    //Replace space with underscore
    account=account.replace(/ /g,"_");
    var nameRange = 'This Week!'+account;
    var range = ss.getRangeByName(nameRange);
    var rangeRows = range.getNumRows();
    n_rows-=1;
    Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
    Logger.log(rangeRows);
    Logger.log(range.getRow());
    Logger.log(range.getLastRow());
    if(rangeRows == 2){
      //add row      
      ws.insertRowsBefore(range.getLastRow(),n_rows);
      //Show all rows in the namedRange
      ws.showRows(range.getRow(),range.getNumRows()+n_rows);
      
    }
    else if (rangeRows > 2) {
      //revert subtracted row count
      n_rows+=1;
      //add row      
      ws.insertRowsBefore(range.getLastRow(),n_rows);
      //Show all rows in the namedRange
      ws.showRows(range.getRow(),range.getNumRows()+n_rows);
    }

    //Get formula in the header row in column E
    var formula = ws.getRange(range.getRow(),5).getFormula();
    Logger.log(formula);
    //Add formula in the newly added rows
    for (var i = 0; i<n_rows; i++){
      Logger.log("row: "+(range.getLastRow()+i));
      ws.getRange(range.getLastRow()+i,5).setFormula(formula);
    }
 }
```

You can refer to this sample code to adjust your other menu. You can remove unnecessary logs, I just used them for debugging

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues when implementing the solution

Comment: I have made an edit to the original post showing the code that I modified, but the script doesn't run.

Comment: can you share your latest sample sheet

Comment: `rangeRows` is undefined. And are you sure you want to overwrite `n_rows`  variable in `var n_rows = range.getNumRows();`. You might be planning on this instead `var rangeRows = range.getNumRows();`

Comment: Sample sheet has been added. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zxdqkksdORfAUlmhnQmefKpxn8n-hB-3YeHdRiNLCLs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: glad to hear that

Comment: How would I get the formula from Column E and copy it to all new added rows?

Comment: which formula are you referring to? the one in `E3`? originally your blank row column E has a data validation drop-down list.

Comment: Thats correct, the formula in `E3`. I would like to keep the data validation if possible and just copy the formula to any rows that are added using the script above.

Comment: which column do you expect to paste the formula in `E3`?. Please provide a sample sheet with your latest code and your expected output

Comment: I have updated the code in the previous sample sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zxdqkksdORfAUlmhnQmefKpxn8n-hB-3YeHdRiNLCLs/edit#gid=731275884

Comment: Please refer to the updated answer. Just remove the logs if unnecessary

Comment: This works as expected the first time rows are added, but subsequent adding of rows causes the second to last row in column E to be empty. I even tried moving it into the `IF / ELSE` statements with +1 after n_rows `for (var i = 0; i<n_rows+1; i++){
      ws.getRange(range.getLastRow()+i,5).setFormula(formula);
    }` but the second to last row is still empty.

Comment: It is working from my side. I tried to add 5 rows 3 times for Big Canyon and all the added rows has formula. (except the original initial row). Here's my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DuCZBNeej_j-JqqeL0Py4h6lkySPjsRjVlPpNJ6OMhA/edit?usp=sharing)